# Let ABCD be a trapezoid; find point M on AB, such that $DM+MC$ is minimal possible

Tags: geometry, inequality, contest-math, problem-solving

Let ABCD be a trapezoid with $A=B=90$, $AD=a$ and $AB=BC=2a$.

Find point M on AB, such that $DM+MC$ is minimal possible.
[image]

I have been trying to do this question, but without success. I have succeeded in proving that $DA+AC<DB+BC$ something which I believe would help in finding this minimal value, however I have not succeeded in finishing it off. Moreover, I have also found that from Pythagoras we have that $DA+AC=a+2a\sqrt{2}$ and $DB+BC=2a+a\sqrt{5}$. Can someone please help me finish the question off?

Comment: A *trapeze* is a piece of equipment for performing aerial acrobatics.  In America we call that shape a *trapezoid*

Comment: Ok Thanks a lot @J.W.Tanner I've just edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to solve -

Choose a point $M$ on $AB$ such that $AM = x, \,$ then BM = $(2a-x)$

$DM = \sqrt{AD^2 + AM^2} = \sqrt{a^2+x^2}$

Similarly $MC = \sqrt{BC^2 + BM^2} = \sqrt{4a^2+(2a-x)^2}$

$L = DM + MC = \sqrt{a^2+x^2} + \sqrt{8a^2+ x^2 - 4ax}$

To find min value of $L$,

$ \displaystyle \frac{dL}{dx} = \frac {x} {\sqrt{a^2+x^2}} + \frac{x-2a}{\sqrt{8a^2+ x^2 - 4ax}} = 0$

$\displaystyle x \sqrt{8a^2+ x^2 - 4ax} + (x-2a) \sqrt{a^2+x^2}  = 0$

$\displaystyle x \sqrt{8a^2+ x^2 - 4ax} =  (2a-x) \sqrt{a^2+x^2}$

$\displaystyle x^2 (8a^2+ x^2 - 4ax) =  (2a-x)^2 (a^2+x^2)$

Solving we get,

$ \displaystyle (x + \frac{2a}{3})^2 = \frac{16a^2}{9}$

So, $x = \frac{2a}{3}$ or $x = -2a$

Discarding $x = -2a$, $AM = x = \frac{2a}{3}$ gives you min.

**EDIT: Just added a diagram for what Calvin Lin suggested which uses reflection -**

$DM + MC$ will minimize  when it is a straight line.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Reflect $C$ about $AB$ to $C'$.

Comment: @Michael Any way you slice it, the math is ugly.  The whole point of the problem is to avoid the ugliness via geometry.  What Calvin Lin's answer means is that if you choose any point M on AB, going from DM + MC = going from DM + MC'.  Further, it is immediate that since the shortest distance between D and C' is a straight line, choose M so that the three points, D, M, C' are collinear.  Given the "contest-math" tag, this type of thinking to avoid the ugliness of the straight forward math is *fair game.*

Comment: +1 Reflection is the way! I was drawing diagram for reflection when your hint came :) Had to change course.

Comment: @MathLover I also was planning on *answering*, when I noticed that Calvin Lin had beaten me to it.  Maybe we could get a class action suit against Calvin Lin for our rep points.